# Encryption Decryption of Password using TripleDES

Tags: asp.net

i am working on login application and i have to Encrypt and Decrypt Password using TripleDES and i have a set of coding and that coding Encryption is working good but Decryption is not working it is showing an error.

**and the error is:**

```
The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or a non-white space character among the padding characters.
```

**and the coding is:**

**newuser.aspx.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace WebApplication5
{
    public partial class WebForm6 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        SqlConnection connection;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TestQueryConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        }

        protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection con1 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TestQueryConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            con1.Open();

            SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("select * from admin where USERNAME=@USERNAME and PASSWORD=@PASSWORD ", con1);
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", txtUserName.Text);
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", txtPassword.Text);
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
            if (dr.HasRows)
            {
                ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "validation", "<script language='javascript'>alert('userName is already availables')</script>");

            }

            else
            {

                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TestQueryConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
                con.Open();
                string strQuery = "insert into admin( USERNAME,PASSWORD) values('" + txtUserName.Text +
                "','" + EncryptTripleDES(txtPassword.Text) + "')";
                connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TestQueryConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
                connection.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery, connection);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                connection.Close();
                Response.Redirect("login.aspx");

            }

            con1.Close();
        }



        public static string EncryptTripleDES(string value)
        {
            TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider cryptoProvider = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
            MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, cryptoProvider.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
            StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(cryptoStream);
            streamWriter.Write(value);
            streamWriter.Flush();
            cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
            memoryStream.Flush();
            return Convert.ToBase64String(memoryStream.GetBuffer(), 0, Convert.ToInt32(memoryStream.Length));
        }

    }
}
```

**login.aspx.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.IO;

namespace WebApplication5
{
    public partial class WebForm4 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        SqlConnection connection;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TestQueryConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        }

        protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection con1 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TestQueryConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            con1.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("select * from admin where USERNAME=@USERNAME and PASSWORD=@PASSWORD ", con1);
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", txtUserName.Text);
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", EncryptTripleDES(DecryptTripleDES(txtPassword.Text)));
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd1);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                Response.Redirect("emplist.aspx");
            }
            else
            {
                ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "validation", "<script language='javascript'>alert('Invalid Username and Password')</script>");
            }
            con1.Close();
        }
        protected void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtUserName.Text = "";
            txtPassword.Text = "";
        }



        public static string EncryptTripleDES(string value)
        {
            TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider cryptoProvider = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
            MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, cryptoProvider.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
            StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(cryptoStream);
            streamWriter.Write(value);
            streamWriter.Flush();
            cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
            memoryStream.Flush();
            return Convert.ToBase64String(memoryStream.GetBuffer(), 0, Convert.ToInt32(memoryStream.Length));
        }


        public static string DecryptTripleDES(string value)
        {
            TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider cryptoProvider = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
            byte[] buffer = Convert.FromBase64String(value);
            MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(buffer);
            CryptoStream cryptoSteam = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, cryptoProvider.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read);
            StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(cryptoSteam);
            return streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        }

    }

}
```

and plz help me on this coding pbl......,

Comment: Why do you decrypt+encrypt, to fill that password parameter? The net result should be equal to `txtPassword.Text`. Apart from the fact that you are decrypting a plain-text value, as fredrik noted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see it, the problem is in two places:

```
byte[] buffer = Convert.FromBase64String(value);
```

int the `DecryptTripleDES()` function and

```
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", EncryptTripleDES(DecryptTripleDES(txtPassword.Text)));
```

in you button submit handler.

On the first line you try to convert a Base64-encoded string into an array of bytes. All well and good if it wasn't for the fact that in this case it probably is just some random text, or a password, entered by the user into the txtPassword control.

Or do you expect users to manually encrypt the password, Base64-encode it and then enter it into the txtPassword field?

Try doing this instead:

```
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", EncryptTripleDES(txtPassword.Text));
```

Comment: ,ya its ok but still it is not working it is showing Invalid Username and Password what does it means....,

Comment: DES requires a symmetric encryption key. I cannot see that you supply one. Which probably means that it will use a new one on each encryption. Hence you will never be able to match what is in the database... You need to either provide a key or switch to a hashing algorithm (such as SHA-512).